# Both MQ versions needs to exists on server

Tags: ibm-mq

In our queue manager we have IBM MQ V7.0.1.3 is running.
Now we need to install IBM MQ V8.0 as a second installation on the same queue manager where IBM MQ V7.0.1.3 is running. Both the product versions need to exist.
How can we ensure both versions will run without impacting each other?

Answer (score 4):

> we have IBM MQ V7.0.1.3 is running.

You do realize that MQ v7.0 is long out of support.  Secondly, you need to be at a minimum of 7.0.1.6 for support for multi-install.

Finally, the only supported versions (as of right now) of IBM MQ are v7.5, v8.0 and v9.0.  See here for more information on end of service dates: http://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=4279

Comment: Thank you Roger!!

Answer (score 2):

First you should move the existing IBM MQ v7.0.1.3 to IBM MQ v7.0.1.6,because 7.0.1.6 was shipped with some fixes to make Version 7.0.1 compatible with a later version on the same server. From IBM MQ v7.1, multiple installations are supported.Following is the infocenter link which explains regarding the same
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q006660_.htm